# how to update variable values from jQuery to d3

Tags: jquery, joomla, svg, d3.js

I'm working on a Joomla 2.5 web site which contains a multiple choice language test (English and Thai). When an item is selected by a mouse click, a percent correct value is calculated using jQuery and stored in a global variable. This variable is updated after each mouse click. My aim has been to display these data in a d3 pie chart. I've got the pie chart working to the point where it displays the initial values of the global variable but it does not respond as the value is updated. .
Following the suggestion in:
stackoverflow.com/questions/9063383/how-to-invoke-click-event-programmaticaly-in-d3
I installed the d3Click function and placed a function call after the global variables had been updated.

jQuery code

```
var E2tw = {};
E2tw.clickCount = 0;
E2tw.clickCorrectCount = 10;
E2tw.percentCorrect = 0;  //  d3 code is accessing this variable initially but not its updates

jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    // function comes from 
  jQuery.fn.d3Click = function () {
    this.each(function (i, e) {
      var evt = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
      evt.initMouseEvent("click", true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
      e.dispatchEvent(evt);
      alert(evt);
    });
  };
// response to selection by click of correct response  - code for incorrect responses similar 
  jQuery("div#answers span.audio").click(function (evnt) {
            .....
      // code selecting audio files and various text highlighting indicating correct choice
            .....     
      E2tw.clickCount++;
      E2tw.clickCorrectCount++;
      E2tw.percentCorrect = ((E2tw.clickCorrectCount/E2tw.clickCount)*100).toFixed(0);
      jQuery("span#data").html(E2tw.percentCorrect);  // displays results in a box, temporary
      jQuery("d3.svg").d3Click();    // this doesn't work
      audioElement.load();    
      audioElement.play();
      E2tw.audioIsPlaying = true;
      audioElement.addEventListener("ended", function() {
        E2tw.audioIsPlaying = false;    
      }); 
     };  
    };
  });
}
```

d3 code for pie chart

```
// from "Interactive Data Visualization" chptr 11 Scott Murray
//Width and height
var w = 150;
var h = 150;
 //E2tw.percentCorrect jquery global variable 
var dataset = [E2tw.percentCorrect, (100 - E2tw.percentCorrect)];  
var outerRadius = w/2;
var innerRadius = w/5;
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
    .innerRadius(innerRadius)
    .outerRadius(outerRadius);
var pie = d3.layout.pie();
//Easy colors accessible via a 10-step ordinal scale
var color = d3.scale.category10();
//Create SVG element
var svg = d3.select("div#innerBM103")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);     
//Set up groups
var arcs = svg.selectAll("g.arc")
    .data(pie(dataset))
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .attr("class", "arc")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + outerRadius + "," + outerRadius + ")");           
            //Draw arc paths
arcs.append("path")
    .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
        return color(i);
    })
    .attr("d", arc);
```

An alert in d3Click does not display suggesting it is not being called. I'm not sure what would be the correct d3 element to include as the d3Click argument. I tried “d3.svg” and “svg”. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You can simply call the function to update the pie chart in the same place where you update the global variable. There's no need to have extra events.

Comment: Thank you for your comment but I'm sorry I don't follow you. Which function for updating are you referring to?

Comment: This would be the block after `jQuery("div#answers span.audio").click(function (evnt) {`.

Comment: It looks like you only have an .enter() component in your d3 code. Take a look at Mike Bostock's general update pattern examples http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3808218

Comment: OK, the d3 pie code is only run when the page loads initially, before the block is called (by a click). After a click, the global variables are upgraded but the pie code is not. This is what prompted me to insert the d3Click code, but it's not being called. At first, I thought that changing the global variables (with a click event) would force the pie code to run, but this doesn't seem to be happening.

Comment: @AndrewStaroscik  that looks promising. I check it out, thanks

Comment: I've looked at the link and, clearly, I'm missing something obvious here, but I still can't see by what means, once the global variable (E2tw_percentCorrect) is updated, the pie code will run. The pie code runs only on page load not after a click event. I'm puzzled.